# Magento 2 - minifying javascript - min.js files not generated

Tags: magento2

**My environment:**

- Magento 2.0.4
- Production mode enabled
- Cache enabled.

I wanted to speed up my Magento 2 store by minifying all Javascript codes. I enabled the JS Minifying option in admin panel and left the rest options (merging and budnling) set to 'no'.

After that all JS scripts stopped working: `menus, cart, checkout etc.`

There are many errors in console listed. However, they are mainly about missing min.js files. They were simply didn't generated somehow.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you deployed static contents? Use php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy to deploy static contents.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but no sinlge min.js file was generated .

Comment: Same problem, ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error happens when i have not setup permission correctly.

Try running:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;  && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
sudo chown -R $(whoami):www-data .
```

Change www-data to appropriate web server user. e.g. apache or www-data

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be to see if you can find the file it's trying to load on the filesystem. If it's there, it would point to a web server configuration problem instead. Which web server are you on apache2 or nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention solution that worked for me - if you use multiple languages then make sure you try deploying static content with explicitly specify languages

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US sk_SK
```

Of course change language codes accordingly

Answer (score -1):

please also enable "Enable JavaScript Bundling" option

store->configuration->advanced->developer->javascript setting->

Enable JavaScript Bundling set to "yes"

and flus cache

I hope it's help you

after Enable JavaScript Bundling run following command

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: It didn't help. Still no minified JS files generated